# Creating a dataframe looping through multiple read_html links

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python and I'm trying to scrape a table from multiple pages of a website.

After reading multiple websites and watching videos, I've managed to write a code that is capable of scraping a single page and saving it to excel. 
The urls for pagination is to simply change the page=x value at the end of the url. I've tried and failed to loop through multiple pages and create a dataframe.

Single page scrape

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

urlbase = "https://www.olx.in/coimbatore/?&page=1"
res = requests.get(urlbase)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', id="offers_table")
df = pd.read_html(str(table), header=1)

df[0].rename(index=str, columns={"Unnamed: 0": "Full Desc", "Unnamed: 2": 
"Detail", "Unnamed: 3": "Price", "Unnamed: 4": "Time"}, inplace = True)
df[0].dropna(thresh=3).to_excel('new.xlsx', sheet_name='Page_2', columns= 
['Detail','Price','Time'], index = False)
```

Scraping multiple pages

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

urlbase = "https://www.olx.in/coimbatore/?&page="

for x in range (4)[1:]:
 res = requests.get(urlbase + str(x))
```

Then create a dataframe by combining multiple dataframes created from each page.
I don't know how to create multiple dataframes in a loop and combine them together.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to create multiple dataframes in a loop and combine them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you can use:

```
frames = []
for x in range (4):
    res = requests.get(urlbase + str(x))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', id="offers_table")
    df = pd.read_html(str(table), header=1)
    df[0].rename(index=str, columns={"Unnamed: 0": "Full Desc", "Unnamed: 2": 
        "Detail", "Unnamed: 3": "Price", "Unnamed: 4": "Time"}, inplace = True)
    frames.append(df[0].dropna(thresh=3))
res = pd.concat(frames)
res.to_excel('new.xlsx', sheet_name='Page_2', columns= ['Detail','Price','Time'], index = False)
```

Comment: This is perfect ! Thank you